# Заменить два регулярных выражения одним

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Есть регулярное выражение вида

```
data = re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', re.sub(r'[^\w]', ' ', data)).strip()
```

Оно заменяет все небуквенные символы на пробелы и удаляет лишние

Можно ли его заменить на одно регулярное выражение, чтобы потом можно было его заранее скомпилить?

Comment: `\W` находит также все те символы, которые находит `\s`. Поэтому достаточно `\W+`. Кстати, как насчёт `_`? Может, лучше `[\W_]+`?

Comment: Да, этого достаточно, спасибо. Насчет нижнего подчеркивания - оно должно быть пунктуацией, так что его тоже удалять нужно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно. Вот так:

```
data = re.sub(r'\W+', ' ', data).strip()
```

Обратите внимание: W - здесь большая буква, не маленькая!

Comment: У меня такая же регулярка была. А в твоём варианте пробелы по краям остаются, а автор их убирал.

Comment: Справедливое замечание. Действительно, пробелы остаются. Я не видел твоего варианта когда отвечал. К тому же у тебя их целых два :) Сейчас пофиксю свой вариант. Благодарю за участие.

Comment: добавил strip() -- это уберет пробелы с концов

Comment: Я не в курсе, что там у питона с матчингом переводов строк, поэтому написал два варианта :)

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, что-то из этого:

```
data = re.sub(r'\W+', ' ', data).strip()
```

```
data = re.sub(r'(\W+|\s)+', ' ', data).strip()
```